# ogr export gdb to PostGIS doesn't contain geometry for display in GIS

Tags: postgis, ogr, file-geodatabase, osgeo

I'm currently trying to export a .gdb containing polygons to PostGIS which other users will need to display using any software like QGis or ArcGIS.
I'm using ogr fom osgeo to export the GDB to PostGIS using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:[db-connection]" "[.gdb-path]" -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -overwrite -skipfailure -progress
```

This manages to upload everything to PostGIS, however the "wkb_geometry" column uses "bytea" as the dafault datatype and when I try to display the geometries using QGIS I'll get the feedback that my table doesn't contain any geometry-type.

So I guess my question would be: Why does this happen and how can I use osgeo (or other tools) to export a gdb to PostGIS as a "proper"  geometry type?

I'm glad for any help/pointers

Comment: Have you enabled the postgis extension on your database?

Comment: I thought I did, but I didn't =(  Thank you very much - problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to create/enable the postgis extension on your database?

[Because:](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html#postgresql-postgis)

> GEOM_TYPE: The GEOM_TYPE layer creation option can be set to one of
> “geometry”, “geography” (PostGIS >= 1.5), “BYTEA” or “OID” to force
> the type of geometry used for a table. For a PostGIS database,
> “geometry” is the default value